# Is it possible to handle notification data payload from push notification in Gluon's RuntimeArgsService?

Tags: push-notification, javafx-8, android-notifications, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am working on a JavaFX mobile application. Currently I am implementing '**Push Notification**' feature. For that I am using Gluon's 'PushNotificationService' (for registering) and 'RuntimeArgsService' (for listening push notification). I can successfully send push notification to a device. But when printing that message in 'RuntimeArgsService' (message.toString()), all I can see are '**id**', '**title**', '**body**'. There's **no payload data** even though I added some. How do I access notification payload information in 'RuntimeArgsService'?

Comment: Yes, as you can see [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/tip/plugins/plugin-push-notifications/android/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/impl/charm/down/plugins/android/PushGcmListenerService.java#lines-68) those are the only fields that are processed from the bundle.

Comment: So, should I subclass PushGcmLisetenerService and Implement my own logic? Or is there any other workaround to get payload?

Comment: In case you want to give it a try, there is a [fork](https://bitbucket.org/tiainen/charm-down) of Charm Down that has implemented Firebase API. You would need to build it locally and use it instead of the regular Charm Down version.

Comment: Well, I'd give a try then. Will that fork you linked be merged into Charm Down later?